# Fuzzy logic rule generation

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

What is the correct formula for finding the number of rules, having 5 inputs (S, O, F, C, W) and 2 lingustic terms (high and low)?

How many rules will be created in this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct formula. Fuzzy logic rules represent expert knowledge. The number of rules depend how you can combine the inputs. And it depends also on the number of required output variables and output sets. Not all possible combinations need to be handled.

Example for a gas bag/baloon which becomes full and only at the end the pressure increases if it is really very full:

IF PRESSURE IS HIGH THEN GASBAG IS FULL

IF VOLUME IS HIGH THEN GASBAG IS FULL

IF VOLUME IS LOW THEN GASBAG IS EMPTY

BUT NOT:

IF PRESSURE IS LOW THEN ...